# Can input values in python be arguments in a python function?

Tags: python, function, input, parameters, arguments

I am trying to call a function in Python but I get the error:

> File "<exec>", line 11, in <module>
> NameError: name 'item_bought_1' is not defined`

I am making a simple program in Python that asks the user for an item they have bought, the price and quantity of items bought. It later on displays the input in a table format. I have not included that code here. Here is the relevant initial code (that asks the user to key in the item, price and quantity, as well as computes the total per item):

```
#ask the user what item they intend to buy as well as the unit price and number of items they intend to buy

item_bought_1 = input("What item has been bought?")
unit_price_1 = input("How much is each unit of " + item_bought_1)
quantity_1 = input("How many units of "+ item_bought_1 + " have been bought?")

item_total_1 = int(unit_price_1) * int(quantity_1)



item_bought_2 = input("ITEM 2::: What item has been bought?")
unit_price_2 = input("How much is each unit of " + item_bought_2)
quantity_2 = input("How many units of "+ item_bought_2 + " have been bought?")

item_total_2 = int(unit_price_2) * int(quantity_2)


item_bought_3 = input("ITEM 3:::What item has been bought?")
unit_price_3 = input("How much is each unit of " + item_bought_3)
quantity_3 = input("How many units of "+ item_bought_3 + " have been bought?")

item_total_3 = int(unit_price_3) * int(quantity_3)


item_bought_4 = input("iTEM 4:::What item has been bought?")
unit_price_4 = input("How much is each unit of " + item_bought_4)
quantity_4 = input("How many units of "+ item_bought_4 + " have been bought?")

item_total_4 = int(unit_price_4) * int(quantity_4)
```

I am trying to make the code less repetitive by using a function:

```
#ask the user what item they intend to buy as well as the unit price and number of items they intend to buy

def question_asker(item_bought, unit_price, quantity, item_total):
    item_bought = input("What item has been bought?")
    unit_price = input("How much is each unit of " + item_bought)
    quantity = input("How many units of "+ item_bought + " have been bought?")

    item_total = int(unit_price) * int(quantity)

    
question_asker(item_bought_1, unit_price_1, quantity_1, item_total_1)
question_asker(item_bought_2, unit_price_2, quantity_2, item_total_2)
question_asker(item_bought_3, unit_price_3, quantity_3, item_total_3)
question_asker(item_bought_4, unit_price_4, quantity_4, item_total_4)
```

But I get the error:

```
 File "<exec>", line 11, in <module>
NameError: name 'item_bought_1' is not defined
```

Am I calling the function correctly? Where is my problem?

Comment: Where is the definition of item_bought_1?

Comment: If you start appending numbers to the names of your variables, you are doing something wrong (at least in 99.9% of all cases). Use an appropriate data structure such as a list.

Comment: @MarcoF. I had not defined it. I have seen how to do so in your answer down below. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the tip. I'll improve the program as I gain more knowledge in python (I've started this year) and programming in general.

Comment: @MargretMauno Yes, it takes a while to learn the basics and then get a feel for it. The first Python scripts I wrote were an abomination, and I was already an experienced programmer in other languages by then. Have fun with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove arguments and return the results:

```
def question_asker():
    item_bought = input("What item has been bought?")
    unit_price = input("How much is each unit of " + item_bought)
    quantity = input("How many units of "+ item_bought + " have been bought?")
    item_total = int(unit_price) * int(quantity)
    return item_bought,unit_price,quantity,item_total

    
item_bought_1, unit_price_1, quantity_1, item_total_1 = question_asker()
item_bought_2, unit_price_2, quantity_2, item_total_2 = question_asker()
item_bought_3, unit_price_3, quantity_3, item_total_3 = question_asker()
item_bought_4, unit_price_4, quantity_4, item_total_4 = question_asker()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. I didn't know a function can have more than one return value, now I know. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

```py
question_asker(item_bought_1, unit_price_1, quantity_1, item_total_1)
question_asker(item_bought_2, unit_price_2, quantity_2, item_total_2)
question_asker(item_bought_3, unit_price_3, quantity_3, item_total_3)
question_asker(item_bought_4, unit_price_4, quantity_4, item_total_4)
```

None of these variables exists, however `question_asker` does not need any arguments anyway.

You should change `def question_asker(item_bought, unit_price, quantity, item_total):` to `def question_asker():` then call it how many times you need, in this case

```py
question_asker()
question_asker()
question_asker()
question_asker()
```

Note that you need to decide whatever it should return, if at all. It might make sense to return `item_total`:

```py
def question_asker():
    ...
    
    item_total = int(unit_price) * int(quantity)

    return item_total

...

item_total_1 = question_asker()
item_total_2 = question_asker()
item_total_3 = question_asker()
item_total_4 = question_asker()
```

At this point you may want to use a `for` loop to call the function and a list or a dictionary to store the values, see [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is my first question on stack overflow :-) Your answer works perfectly fine. Though in my case I would need multiple return values since each of the variables will be required later on when I'm making a table of items bought with their quantity, price and total... Once again I'm super thankful for your answer.